# resource handler returned message: "The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

This is my lambda cf template, when I deploy it to cloudformation, I got this error, I googled it but didn't find a answer to solve my problem, can anyone help me with that?

Resource handler returned message: "The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda. (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: b1484f34-b9b3-4000-af95-5a483649fb40, Extended Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: 9da1e852-6e03-80c5-e72c-cb978a6bce0f, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

```
ConfigurationLambdaRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      RoleName: 'configuration-sqs-lambda1'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - events.amazonaws.com
                - s3.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSQSFullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLogsFullAccess

  ConfigurationLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: 'configuration service with lambda'
      FunctionName: 'configuration-lambda1'
      Handler: lambda.handler.EventHandler::handleRequest
      Runtime: java8
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 120
      Code:
        S3Bucket: configurationlambda
        S3Key: lambda-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      Role: !GetAtt ConfigurationLambdaRole.Arn

  ConfigurationLambdaInvokePermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - ConfigurationLambdaFunction
          - Arn
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      Principal: "sqs.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: 'arn:aws:s3:::configurationlambda'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your role does not allow Lambda service to assume it. Pretty much what it says on the tin.

A simplified explanation is that Lambda service assumes IAM role in your function's execution environment, and the environment will have necessary permissions and access keys while executing the function code. More details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html

Therefore handler role `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` should have similar layout:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```